# Is there a way to purchase items from the Medal Trader in bulk?

Tags: sword-art-online-fatal-bullet

On the Gov. Office/Lobby of the SBC Glocken you can trade medals for items. The problem is, I want to trade the +10.000 medals that I have for the same item but is really problematic having to choose the item, confirm it twice and repeat the process more than 100 times.

Is there a way to trade medals for items in bulk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In menus that allow you to buy variable amounts of items in bulk or otherwise, the scrolling control tips at the bottom of the screen usually indicate that you can do so. For example, this is part of the bar when you're purchasing weapons from the console in your room aboard the SBC Glocken:

[image: Part of the scrolling menu bar indicating different controls for increasing and decreasing quantity]

However, when attempting to trade medals in for rewards in the SBC Glocken Lobby, these controls do not exist:

[image: The entire bottom bar indicating controls for selecting items]

Therefore, it's safe to assume that you can pretty much only do the whole exchange manually.

(Screenshots from the PC version, but I imagine this interface doesn't have too many major changes on the console release.)

Comment: The interface doesn't change, with an Xbox 360 or Xbox One controller the same information is shown with controller buttons instead of keys.